# Supermicro MBD-X9DRL-IF-O won't work

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, supermicro

It works before, but after I've changed boot to "UEFI only", set boot device to "Built-in UEFI Shell" and enabled "Above 4G" (and maybe done something another), system stuck on code 92 and I can't open settings by pressing DEL. 
I can press TAB, when system starts to see POST, and I'm seeing information about motherboard, but  nothing else. Also I can at this time press DEL and see "Entering setup" caption and again nothing else.

Any solutions? Tried CMOS reset and started with no or one RAM - nothing helps.

Comment: Did you look in the manual to find out what Code 92 represents?

Comment: I find no codes in manual.

Comment: But in web I found that 92 means BIOS data table check.

Comment: did you manage to solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Old, but I had a similar problem. Supermicro X10SL7-F, after changing some BIOS settings it would not POST past code 91 (which, IIRC, was some storage system check). I tried clearing the CMOS. I tried recovery mode (renaming a BIOS update firmware file as "Super.ROM" and placing it on the root of a FAT formatted USB drive). That too would get stuck at code 92.

But really, it shouldn't need new firmware, just the settings were borked I figured. I tried clearing the CMOS one more time, holding a paper clip across the jumpers for like 30 seconds (power was disconnected), and then trying again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. You need the IPMI key to reflash your BIOS, after its flashed it will work again. You can buy them for like $20, or usually SuperMicro will send you one for free if you ask.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem on supermicro X12DPU-6. post code did not go beyond 92. I took out the CMOS battery, turned it over and attached the positive terminal to the board contacts. I held it for 1 minute, with the power turned off, of course. After that inserted the battery normally and started the server. I was able to go into bios and make settings